# Find record with an empty relation

Tags: prisma

Say I have this prisma schema with an implicit m:n-relation of `Post` and `Tag`

```
model Post {
  id   String @id
  tags Tag[]
}

model Tag {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  posts Post[]
}
```

How do I find the first `Post` that has **no** associated `Tag`s?

```js
prisma.post.findFirst({
  where: {
    tags: {
      // are nonexistent (something like count === 0?)
    },
  },
}),
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use `orderBy` by count of tags in ascending order and get the first one? Like that:

```
prisma.post.findFirst({
  orderBy: { tags: { _count: 'asc' } },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching on the internet I've found a link where the official documentation gives information on how to manage lists --> [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#scalar-list-filters)

There it gives this example:

```
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
  where: {
    tags: {
      isEmpty: true,
    },
  },
})
```

Try adapting that to your own situation.

Comment: But OP has a relation, not a list. Otherwise it would work, yeah